# Disabling Mouse Wheel Scrolling in ItemsGrid View

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm using a grouped Items Page template from MSFT and wanting to disable horizontal scrolling for a specific reason. I did this by setting Scrollviewer.HorizontalScrollScrollbarVisibility = "Disabled". It seems to be disabled when I tried to drag the screen left or right but works perfectly when I use the mousewheel instead. can you help as to how to prevent horizontal scrolling while using mouse wheel ?

```
 <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
    <local:VariableGridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
    Padding="116,137,40,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTileItem}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    >
```

Comment: And it is scrolling butter smooth in Samsung Slate even despite setting the IsSwipe enabled property to false. Can somebody help asap

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set the HorizontalScrollMode property of the ScrollViewer to "Disabled". See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode.aspx).

Your xaml should be:

```
<local:VariableGridView
x:Name="itemGridView"
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
Padding="116,137,40,46"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTileItem}"
SelectionMode="None"
IsSwipeEnabled="False"
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
>
```

Comment: That's typically not helping Chris !!! Would request you try setting this properties to false and share your findings

Comment: I had already tried Setting ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" on a GridView element of a fresh Windows Store Grid App project, and it works exactly as you requested with (mouse wheel has no effect).  Are you saying you tried this and it didn't work for you?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your time again. Just have a look @ the code (appending as a part of my question) snippet that I ve used and correct me if am wrong !!!